# When Ubuntu 18.04 deploys zabbix4.0, the database type is PostgreSQL instead of MySQL. How can I set this to support MySQL?

Tags: mysql, apache, ubuntu-18.04, zabbix

In Ubuntu 18.04 server, I use binary file to install zabbix4.0 according to the official website document of zabbix4.0, and I use MySQL 5.7.30 database. After installation, when I configure the front end of zabbix4.0,In the database configuration page, I only see one option of PostgreSQL, not mysql, as shown in the following figure:
[image]

In my server, I have installed MySQL version 5.7.30, and imported the data of ZABBIX 4.0 into the ZABBIX database, without any PostgreSQL installed

Excuse me, how can I make zabbix4.0 support MySQL 5.7.30 that I have installed? Thank you!

I installed zabbix4.0 according to the official documents:
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/zh/manual/installation/install_from_packages/debian_ubuntu

This is my installation method:

```
# install zabbix
cd ~/download
wget https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/4.0/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zabbix- 
release/zabbix-release_ 4.0-2+bionic_ all.deb
sudo dpkg -i zabbix-release_ 4.0-2+bionic_ all.deb
sudo apt-get update

#install Server/proxy/
sudo apt-get install -y zabbix-server-mysql
sudo apt-get install -y zabbix-frontend-php
```

Answer (score 0):

With Ubuntu, you got two type of databases when donwloading Zabbix, PostgreSql and MySql. You need to re-download (I mean installation and configuration) Zabbix choosing MySql as database.
The following link could help [Zabbix (Ubuntu) with MySql as database](https://www.zabbix.com/download?zabbix=5.0&os_distribution=ubuntu&os_version=18.04_bionic&db=mysql&ws=apache)

Comment: I have attached my installation method. Is this a MySQL supported method?

Answer (score 0):

The current version of the package is 4.0-3, so instead, you must do this :

**Install repository**

```
# wget https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/4.0/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zabbix-release/zabbix-release_4.0-3+bionic_all.deb
# sudo dpkg -i zabbix-release_4.0-3+bionic_all.deb
# sudo apt update
```

**Install server, frontend, agent**

```
# sudo apt install zabbix-server-mysql zabbix-frontend-php zabbix-agent
```

Comment: OK, I'll try again